# How to integrate Paypal Payment Method in iOS App Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, swift4

I'm working on an app in which PayPal payment gateway is to integrate. As such I have gone through several blog but did not found it helpful. 
So if any can suggest something that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For integrating Paypal payment into your swift ios application, you would need to use Braintree SDK which provides all the inbuilt functions for implementation.

Its always better to implement client-server architecture for payment where the server would have the business logic and client would provide an interface for payment.Kindly create a sandbox account for testing and development purpose.

You can learn about the basic architecture of implementation from the documentation.Code snippets are also provided in the documentation to ease the integration process.

1. [Overview and architecture](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview) - this would provide basic information about the structure and process
2. [This the api guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/overview) - overall guide to implement client and server.
3. [Drop in UI](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v3)  - Payment UI using SDK

Comment: Does this support AED currency format for payment ?

Comment: Yes,All these currencies are supported - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/currencies

Comment: were you able to get the way through?

Answer (score 1):

There is also the possibility to integrate PayPal without Braintree, only via the PayPal API and ASWebAuthenticationSession (SFAuthenticationSession)

**1 Step:** Create an order via the PayPal API, in the **application_context** object the **return_url** must point to a http/https: domain for example "https://mydomain/paypalpaymentredirect.html" (bug in the PayPal API), there you have to configure the redirect to the url scheme you specified in the ASWebAuthenticationSession (myApp://return_from_paypal).

Visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app for more Information of how to add a new URL scheme to your App.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

Sample Request:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "100.00"
      }
    }
  ],
  "order_application_context" : {
    "return_url" : "https://www.someDomain.de/redirectToMyAppScheme"
  }
}'
```

**2 Step:** after the successful creation of the order the PayPal API will return the approve URL to you, with this URL the ASWebAuthenticationSession will be started, after the user has passed the PayPal flow you will get the callBack URL in the completionHandler, in case of success the token and the PayerID will be attached.

CodeSample:

```
webAuthSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(url: URL(string: "https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5O190127TN364715T") , callbackURLScheme: "myApp://return_from_paypal", completionHandler: { (callBack: URL?, error: Error?) in
```

**3 Step:** after step 2 has been completed successfully, you can now successfully complete the order at PayPal using the capture URL that you received when creating the order. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture

Sample Request

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T/capture \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-H "PayPal-Request-Id: 7b92603e-77ed-4896-8e78-5dea2050476a
```

"

Comment: Hi , i am trying to connect using these methods but it does not return to my application is there any thing updated regarding this.

Comment: Hi i have this configuration live in my App, still working. Have you replaced the return URL by your own Domain and configured there the redirect to your Apps URL Scheme? In Xcode you have to configure you URL Scheme under Project -> you main target -> Info. There you can add the Scheme unter URL Types.